# What does the Rounding Mode Unnecessary do in Java?

Tags: java

If rounding is required what exactly happens? I was looking in the documentation and it says it just throws an exception, yet in my application it seems to be rounding with half up.

Comment: And also which documentation you were looking at.

Answer (score 7):

`RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY` mandates that a `BigDecimal` does not need to be rounded to fit the scale specified by it.

Here's a sample:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.1").setScale(1, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
```

1.1 is an *exact* result, and when the new `BigDecimal` is created as a result of `setScale`, it does not need to round the result to get that precise value.

It would also work if you blew out the scale:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.1").setScale(1_000, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
```

...but, it would break if you tried something like this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.12").setScale(1, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
```

The reason for that:  you have to round your `BigDecimal` now in order for you to represent the appropriate scale (1 number after the decimal).

You wouldn't see the behavior if you had your scale larger than the amount of digits after your decimal, but may see another rounding behavior if it was already established on that instance of your `BigDecimal`.  [You have complete control over the rounding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), so use that judiciously.